# How to Print out an array of String periodically on JSF

Tags: java, arrays, primefaces

I want to print out an Array of Strings periodically on my JSF page, but I am not able to achieve this.  The JSF is only printing out the entire Array at once and not periodically.

This is my XHTML code:

```
<h:form>
<h:outputText id="eventener" value="#{eventBean.names}" />
  <p:poll interval="2" listener="#{eventBean.names}" update="eventener" />
  </h:form>
```

This is my bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EventBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> names;

    @PostConstruct
    public void namesInterval() {

        names = Arrays.asList("Steve is late for work", "Segun is coming back next week", "Tope is a beautiful girl");
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what are you trying to do.  Do you want to print every item in the array at once? When you're updating (adding items) your array?

You're not updating your array at any momento, the poll is working as intended.  On your **listener** attribute you set what you want every 2 seconds, like refreshing your array from an external source. If you're trying to print an item from the array every 2 seconds, you can try something like this

```
<h:form>
<h:outputText id="eventener" value="#{eventBean.item}" />
    <p:poll interval="2" listener="#{eventBean.pollListener}" update="eventener" />
</h:form>
```

**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EventBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> names;
    private String item;
    private int count;

    @PostConstruct
    public void namesInterval() {
        names = Arrays.asList("Steve is late for work", "Segun is coming back next week", "Tope is a beautiful girl");
        count = 0;
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public String getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void pollListener(){
        //you can use an iterator too
        if (count >= names.size())
        {
            count = 0;
        }
        item = names.get(count);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried using that but it's only printing the first index of the array ("Steve is late for work") every 2 seconds, i will be glad if you can help me modify it, cause i've tried different modification but its still printing out the first index over and over

Comment: I forgot to add the `count++`, try again.

Comment: It's still giving the same result.

Comment: which version of primefaces are you using @mcastilloy2k

Comment: Recently updated to 6.0.  Check with the debbuger the values, if the listener is being called by the poll.

Comment: Yea, the debugger is only seeing count as 0

Comment: Please, post your updated code, and I'll test on my local enviroment.